# I can't access code from subdirectories in F#

Tags: f#

I am trying to get my head around how F# code is organised.

I understand that in a folder or main directory - to access code from a different file, the file must be above it, and I can move code up or down using Alt+Up , Alt+Down - makes sense.

However, if I Have some code in a subdirectory - even if that subdirectory is above the code it does not appear to be able to access it. If the subdirectory is in a parent directory it seems to be Ok.  I can't seem to find the rationale for that anywhere. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, if I Have some code in a subdirectory - even if that subdirectory is above the code it does not appear to be able to access it.

This doesn't sound correct. All that matters is the order of the files in the project file, so if you have this in your `.fsproj` file:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="MyFolder\MyFile.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Then `Program.fs` can access things defined in `MyFolder\MyFile.fs`. If you are seeing something different, please share the details.

Comment: So it looks like you can - but there is a bug.  If I create a subdirectory - and then access some code ( using open xxx.xxx.xxx ) in a parent directory above the code - then it shows it as a bug.

But - if I move the whole subdirectory down to the bottom of the current parent folder it is fine. Also if I move it back up to where it was - fine.   But if I just left it where it was it will not compile even if I restart VS 2019